# Integrate Orion with a DBaaS like TROVE (Openstack)

Tags: openstack, fiware, fiware-orion

i've developed a E2E application using some FIWARE GE. In particular i used IDAS and ORION. My question is: Can i store orion data in an external db in order to do query SQL or integrate Orion with TROVE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion can be accessed through a REST API to produce (create/upate) or consume (queries and asyncronous notifications) context information, based in an entity/attribute data model. See details in the [Orion documentation manual](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/).

Aas long as you can use that API from your application with that REST API, then you could integrate Orion.

Comment: Hi fgalan, 

thank you for the answer... i know that orion can be accessed through a REST API but i'd like store the information stored in ORION in a DB accessible via query SQL... is it possible?

Comment: Orion used MongoDB as storage DB, which is not based in SQL. However, maybe you could build a bridge system to adapt your SQL queries to MongoDB quereies or (even better) to adapt your SQL queries to Orion REST API. Another option is to dump information from MongoDB to your SQL-based database and do queries on it (I don't know but maybe there is some literature about aprroaches like this one around).